# SET UPDATE, где WHERE задается набором связанных multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Есть таблица `SECURITY_EXCHANGE` со столбцами `security_id` (int), `is_here` (boolean), `market_id` (int)

Пара значений `security_id` и `market_id` уникальные.

Мне нужно обновить ряд значений `is_here` в null.
если я делаю запрос так, то он отрабатывает.

```
UPDATE SECURITY_EXCHANGE
SET is_here = null
WHERE security_id in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Но мне нужно чтобы в `WHERE` учитывались значения в связанных колонках `security_id` + `market_id`.

То есть что-то типа такого:

```
UPDATE SECURITY_EXCHANGE
    SET is_here = null
    WHERE security_id AND market_id in ...;
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: У вас опечатка в заголовке.

Comment: @Глеб изменил..

Comment: `(x = 1 and y =2) OR (x=3 and y=4) OR ...`

Comment: Используем Row constructor: `.. WHERE (security_id, market_id) IN ( (1,2), (3,4), .. ) ..`

Comment: @Akina row contructor есть в SQL Server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как упоминал @Akina.

Вот полная демонстрация с использованием Table Value Constructor.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, security_id INT, market_id INT, is_here BIT DEFAULT(1));
INSERT @tbl (security_id, market_id) VALUES
(1, 2),
(1, 29),
(1, 18),
(1, 3);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- просто чтобы увидеть
SELECT t.* 
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN
    (VALUES
          (1, 29),
          (1, 18)
) AS Params(security_id, market_id)
    ON t.security_id = Params.security_id
        AND t.market_id = Params.market_id;

-- фактическое действие
UPDATE t
SET is_here = null
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN
    (VALUES
          (1, 29),
          (1, 18)
) AS Params(security_id, market_id)
    ON t.security_id = Params.security_id
        AND t.market_id = Params.market_id;

-- тест
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Результат**

| ID | security_id | market_id | is_here |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 29 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | 18 | NULL |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 1 |